# Custom Terraform provider: dial tcp: lookup terraform.local: no such host

Tags: terraform

I have an executable of a terraform provider I have developed, under:

```
.terraform.d/plugins/terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage/darwin_amd64/1.0.0/
```

The /plugins/terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage/darwin_amd64/1.0.0/ path needed to be created by me and did not exist before.My host is a MacOs machine with an intel chip.

However when I try to install the custom plugin like this:

```
terraform {
required_providers {
ecrpushimage = {
  source  = "terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage"
  version = ">= 1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And run terraform init, I get the error:

```
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage:
│ could not connect to terraform.local: failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://terraform.local/.well-known/terraform.json": dial tcp: lookup terraform.local: no such host
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Terraform assumes that you want to install any provider from its "origin registry", which is the hostname that's included as part of its address. In your example, the "origin registry" of this provider is `terraform.local`, and so Terraform is trying to perform [service discovery](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/remote-service-discovery) on that hostname to find its endpoints for [the provider registry protocol](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/provider-registry-protocol).

I assume your intention is to override that default and instead "install" the provider from your local disk. Terraform does support that but you will need to configure your system to opt in to using that different provider installation strategy.

There are three main ways to achieve that:

### Development Overrides

If you are currently in the development phase of your provider and haven't yet published it anywhere to assign it a version number, you can configure a [development override](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#development-overrides-for-provider-developers) which will force `terraform plan`, `terraform apply`, etc to look in a particular local directory for `terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage`, ignoring any work done by `terraform init`. In that case you should not run `terraform init` at all, because your provider is already "installed" in the designated override directory.

Development overrides are a setting in [the CLI configuration file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file), which typically lives in your home directory and is totally separate from the `.tf` files you use to describe the infrastructure you want to create.

```
provider_installation {
  dev_overrides {
    "terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage" = "/home/your-username/dev/terraform-ecrpushimage"
  }
}
```

In the above example `/home/your-username/dev/terraform-ecrpushimage` should be *the directory containing the plugin executable*, and not the executable itself. You can then build a plugin executable directly into that directory so you can iterate quicky without having to "publish" your provider with a version number anywhere:

```
go build -o /home/your-username/dev/terraform-ecrpushimage/terraform-provider-ecrpushimage
```

If your provider doesn't exist in any of the normal installation locations then `terraform init` will still fail because that command's job is to install providers from elsewhere. But that failure is irrelevant during development, because a development override will make other commands like `terraform plan` ignore any packages that `terraform init` might have installed for that provider, and will always use the local override directory instead.

A development override is the option I would recommend when you are actively developing and testing your provider, since it directly models the fact that you are working with builds of your provider that haven't been assigned any version number yet, and that exist only on your development system. The other options in the following sections are for specifying alternative installation methods for provider builds that have already been released (assigned a version number), but that are not published in a typical Terraform provider registry.

### Implied Local Mirror Directories

If you haven't given Terraform any explicit configuration for provider installation strategy then it will build its own automatic provider installation strategy, which includes what I described above about using the provider registry protocol to install from the origin registry.

However, [Terraform does first search a number of local directories](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#implied-local-mirror-directories) -- exactly which ones depend on which operating system you are running Terraform on -- and will configure itself to use only the local filesystem for any provider for which there's at least one version installed in one of those local directories.

Since you are using macOS, you will need to create your mirror directory under one of the following prefixes with today's Terraform (v1.5 is current as I'm writing this):

- `$HOME/.terraform.d/plugins`
- `$HOME/Library/Application Support/io.terraform/plugins`
- `/Library/Application Support/io.terraform/plugins`

From your question it seems like you might have tried to build a local mirror at the first of the above paths. If you did indeed create the directory you mentioned under your home directory, AND if it contains an executable file `terraform-provider-ecrpushimage`, then Terraform should be able to find it and will assume you intend to install `terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage` packages only from that local directory.

This implied behavior only works if there's no `provider_installation` block in your CLI configuration files. If you specify `provider_installation` then you're opting in to explicit configuration, as described in the next section.

### Explicit Local Mirror Directory

With the implied behavior described in the previous section, Terraform effectively constructs itself a virtual provider installation CLI Configuration similar to the following:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/home/your-username/.terraform.d/plugins"
    include = ["terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage"]
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage"]
  }
}
```

You can optionally write [an *explicit* provider installation block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#explicit-installation-method-configuration) like the above into your CLI configuration file, which explicitly tells Terraform:

- For `terraform.local/local/ecrpushimage` in particular, *only* use the local filesystem mirror and never try to contact the `terraform.local` registry for that provider.
- For any other provider, contact its origin registry as normal.

A possible variant of this would be to make `terraform.local` as a whole be mirrored locally, which might be better if you never intend to run a real provider registry at that hostname:

```
provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/home/your-username/.terraform.d/plugins"
    include = ["terraform.local/*/*"]
  }
  direct {
    exclude = ["terraform.local/*/*"]
  }
}
```

This configuration will tell Terraform to never try direct installation for any provider on `terraform.local`, and that the local mirror directory is the *only* installation method for such providers.